# Convert pandas df columns to paired list

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a df like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'col2': [10, 20, 10, 20]})
```

How would I get a list that pairs each row of `col1` and `col2` like so:

```
outputlist = [[1, 10], [1, 20], [2, 10], [2, 20]]
```

I've found ways to turn lists into df columns, but not the other way around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do (see [tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'col2': [10, 20, 10, 20]})

result = df1.values.tolist()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 10], [1, 20], [2, 10], [2, 20]]
```

Comment: Not even sure `tolist` is needed.

Comment: @kabanus What do you mean?

Comment: From OP's requirements the value array might be good enough (maybe better?) Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: How would I select specific columns? eg if I have a `col3`, but I only want `col1` and `col2` to be in the output? I realize I could just drop `col3` and then use `.tolist()`, but I was just curious.

Comment: I guess you could do: `df1[['col1', 'col2']].values.tolist()`